# find special text from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like `#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/`

how i can find last text from string? this place is videos

other strings like

- `#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/`
- `#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/test/testt/`
- `#ls/?folder_path=seff/test/home/videos/`

Comment: You should provide at least a few different strings...

Comment: Do you always have `/` at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a few more example strings, but based off of your one and only example, here's a rough regex to get you started:

```
.*?/\?.*?/(.*?)\//
```

EDIT:

Based on your extended examples:

```
.*?/\?.*/(.*?)\//
```

This regex will consume text until the second to last `/` and capture until the last `/` in the string.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One of them:

```
var str = '#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/'.replace(/\/$/,'');
alert(str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1)); //=> videos
```

Alternative without using `replace`

```
var str = '#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/'
   ,str = str.substr(0,str.length-1)
   ,str = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert(str); //=> videos
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work even if the string doesn't end in /
    var str;

```
var re = /\w+(?=\/?$)/;

str = "#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/"
str.match(re) ; //# => videos

str = "#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/test/testt/"
str.match(re) ; //# => testt

str = "#ls/?folder_path=seff/test/home/videos/"
str.match(re) ; //# => videos


str = "#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/test/testt"
str.match(re) ; //# => testt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\/([^\/]*)\/?$
```

This regex will match all non `/` between the last two `/`. Where the last `/` is optional. The `$` is matching the end of the string.

Your resulting string is then in the first capturing group (because of the `()`) `$1`

You can test it [here](http://regexr.com?2tfjj)

Answer (score 0):

If it always ends with `/` then this will works.

```
var str = '#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/';
var arr = str.split('/');
var index = arr.length-2;
console.log(arr[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is consistent like this string, this is a simple split based way to retreive
your required string: http://jsfiddle.net/EEkLP/

```
var str="#ls/?folder_path=home/videos/";
var strArr = str.split("/");
alert(strArr[strArr.length-2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the last word always enclosed with forward slashes, then you can try this -

```
".+\/([^\/]+)\/$"
```

or in regex notation

```
/.+\/([^\/]+)\/$/
```